# Find a term and catch the following text or after space

Tags: php, regex, whitespace

I have some payment logs`(txt)` and these are some patterns found in the files:

pattern 1:

```
Nickname
                          -- blank space
Jon Doe
```

pattern 2:

```
Nickname:
Jon Doe
```

pattern 3:

```
Nickname: Jon Doe
```

How can I catch all the texts, which in this example would be "Jon Doe", that always is in the next line after the term `(Nickname)` and ignore the blank spaces?

**UPDATE:**
not every "Nickname" has the " : " double-point after it

something like the first pattern

**UPDATE:**
`Nickname` may start with a lowercase `n`.

Comment: You don't need to ignore the blank spaces. You can trim them.

Comment: i want to use regex, but i dont know how.

Comment: Try this: https://regex101.com/r/fPLM70/1

Comment: Thanks, andreas, i forgot to mention but not every "nickname" has the " : " after it, i'm gonna update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex captures the name if there is a : after nickname.
I guess that was a mistake on the first example.

```
$re = '/[Nn]ickname:?\s+.*?(\w+\s\w+)/s';
$str = 'Nickname
               
Jon Doe
pattern 2:

 Nickname:
 Jon Doe
 pattern 3:

 Nickname: Jon Doe';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Try it here; https://regex101.com/r/fPLM70/3

Edit added `:` optional.
Edit2 added N/n in nickname

```
[Nn] is to make it accept both N and n.  
:? Means : can exsists or not.
\s+ means one or more spaces
.*? Because . can mean new line this means any new lines.
(\w+\s\w+) capture word space word
```

Comment: just one more thing, can it be case-insensitive? works with both "Nickname" and "nickname"

Answer (score 1):

This will outperform the other current answers when used with `preg_match_all()` to find multiple occurrences:

```
/[Nn]ickname:?\s+\K[A-Za-z ]+/
```

Code ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fPLM70/5)) ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5cc09f8da1f296d3ff60e2225cdac61f473cd0fa)):

```
$in='Nickname

Jon Doe
pattern 2:

 Nickname:
 Jon Doe
 pattern 3:

 Nickname: Jon Doe';
var_export(preg_match_all('/[Nn]ickname:?\s+\K[A-Za-z ]+/',$in,$out)?$out[0]:[]);
```

The `\K` marks the fullmatch start, so no capture group is needed, this reduces output array size by 50%.

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Jon Doe',
  1 => 'Jon Doe',
  2 => 'Jon Doe',
)
```

Comment: It's a preference thing. Your  output may be smaller size but also lacks the "bug test". Since you only have the results you can't find where it finds what, thus being harder to debug if needed.

Comment: @Andreas, okay.  `/[Nn]ickname:?\s+([A-Za-z ]+)/` uses a capture group and is still more efficient.

Comment: I didn't say you were incorrect. Just said it's a preference. I usually code in such a way that I can easily debug. But if the data in is consistent and nothing really changes, then I guess you answer works very good.

Comment: it also works, really apreciate it, but i'm having some problems with terms that have spaces between the words, something like: "Favorite color", doesnt works

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 `Favorite color` instead of `nickname`?  This task becomes much easier if you can standardize the label that precedes each value.  By ensuring that the label ends in `:` the regex pattern will become much more efficient and accurate.  If you show me your new input string and your pattern, I will help you.

Comment: actually, i just gave one example because the others labels follows the same patterns that i posted, just changing the name of it.

Comment: i have this label called "CPF" and it doesnt match, it has numbers and dots, like: 888.888.848-25

Comment: also year dates such as '11/02/1997'

Comment: I know that this is not the main question of the this, but since it is the same logic, I thought I would take all the values, regardless of whether it was number, text or special characters

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 This is no problem, I can provide a new pattern that accommodates your larger range of inputs.  SO volunteers cannot read minds, we can only build patterns using the information that you give us.  It is important when you post a question that you provide several different input possibilities so that you can receive a high quality answer with less chasing around. The patterns that I write are often very literal to achieve maximum efficiency. You can use this: https://regex101.com/r/fPLM70/7 But for best pattern design, you will need to consider if you need to capture the label or not.

Comment: Only when considering your entire text and what you want to extract and how you need to process the results, can you determine the best pattern to select.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146341/discussion-between-ngthm4r3-and-mickmackusa).

Answer (score 0):

use the `regex` to get your text, and then `trim` it to remove the spaces

```
$fileContent = "Nickname:

Jon Doe";
preg_match('/Nickname:?\n(.*)/s', $fileContent, $match);
//$match[1] contains your line.

echo $match[1];
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was upvoted, it fails. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f615e1d67e53e5bb8fd9e2046cbc63cd0da10a5f

Comment: @mickmackusa it is working here, check this php fiddle //phpfiddle.org/lite?code=<?php\n$fileContent = "Nickname:\n\nJon Doe";\npreg_match('/Nickname:?\n(.*)/s', $fileContent, $match);\n//$match[1] contains your line.\n\necho $match[1];\n\n?>

Comment: I see, there is a `\r` to blame.  Even after adding `\r` before your `\n` , your pattern doesn't return the desired result. Though it would falsely appear to be correct with `echo`.